Individual backside for every tickets
I need to print a set of login informations, on a thing like flashcard (info on the front, password on the back), but the issue is sometimes I need to have multiple info on the back, and I struggle to fully understand the example (flashcard_example) of flashcards (flasCard option on the ticket package), especially the \backside command.
Unless the first thing (argument #1 )is ALWAYS on the back (or the flascard's front) and any other arguments are on the front (flashcard's back).
So how do I trigger the \backside command after the second argument?
%%%
%
% ticket.sty example file for flashcards for word learning
%
%%%%
% use the corresponding paper size for your ticket definition
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,]{letter}

\usepackage[Migros_GAB7203.106,  %% My TDF file per the sticky labels
              crossmark      
              ]{ticket}
\usepackage{graphicx}  % load misc stuff
\usepackage{syntonly}  %to test without output
\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\definecolor{Green4}{HTML}{059108}

% make your default ticket. \ticketdefault is somewhat like a background
\renewcommand{\ticketdefault}{% my background
  %% Strisce verdi
    \put(-1,0){
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ 
            \node[outer sep=0pt,fill=Green4!35, anchor=south west, minimum width=69.9mm,minimum height=4mm] (topBar) {};
        }
    }
}

% now what do you like to put in your ticket
\newcommand{\card}[3]{\ticket{%
    \put(-1.1,0){
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ 
            \node[outer sep=0pt,fill=Green4, anchor=south west, minimum width=11mm,minimum height=42.4mm] (sideBar) {};
            }
    }
    \put(32.5,15){\makebox[0mm]{\centering{\huge{\textbf{#1}}}}}
 }}

\newcommand{\entryroot}[2]{}

\newcommand{\raiz}[3]{\ticket{%
    \put(2,31){{$\sqrt{\enspace}$}}
    \put(32.5,15){\makebox[0mm]{{\huge{\textit{{ #1 }}}}}}
}}

%puts a bullet on the word.
\newcommand{\blt}{$\bullet$\enspace}

%command for the synonyms
\newcommand{\syn}[1]{
  \begin{center}
     \fbox{\parbox[t]{50mm}{\centering{#1}}}
  \end{center}
}

%command for the related words.
\newcommand{\relwords}[1]{$\mathbf{\sim}$ #1}

%command for the examples
\newcommand{\example}[1]{\\[1.5mm]\textit{#1}}




%% you can generate this part from a database!
\begin{document}
\input{words}
% change the commands for the backside
\renewcommand{\card}[3]{\ticket{%
    \put(3,30){\parbox{58mm}{\large{\textbf{ #1:}}}}%
    \put(4,23){\parbox[t]{58mm} {\small {\blt #2}}}%
    \put(8,17){\textit{\small {\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}% added by me
 }}

\renewcommand{\entryroot}[2]{\small{\textbf{#1 }}\textit{\scriptsize{{#2}}}$\|$}

\renewcommand{\raiz}[3]{\ticket{%
    \put(3,30){\parbox{58mm}{\textbf{#1:} #2}}%
    \put(3,13){\parbox{58mm}{#3}}%
 }}

\backside%
\oddsidemargin=6pt
\input{words}
\end{document}

And part of the file words, given by the example;
\raiz{a}{without}{
  \entryroot{amoral}{neither moral nor inmoral}
  \entryroot{anonymous}{of unknown authorship or origin}
  \entryroot{atrophy}{the wasting away of body tissue}
}{PSW1}
\raiz{ab/abs}{off, away from, apart, down}{
  \entryroot{abduct}{to take by force}
  \entryroot{abhor}{to hate detest}
  \entryroot{abdicate}{renbounce of relinquish a throne}
  \entryroot{abstinence}{forbearance from any indulgence of appetite}
}{PSW2}
\card{abate}{to lessen to subside}{PSW3}
\card{abdication}{giving up control authority}{PSW4}
\card{aberration}{straying away from what is normal}{PSW5}
\card{abet}{help, aid\\\blt Act as a complice\\\blt encourage smb
  (in doing wrong)}{PSW6}
\card{abeyance}{Expectancy\\\blt suspended action}{PSW87
\card{abhor}{to hate to detest}{PSW8}
\card{abide}{Stay, dwell\\\blt be faithful to; endure\\\blt continue, bear}{PSW9}

and my tdf file for the sticky labels 70x 42.4 mm, that I'll be putting on DIN A8 papers, into a box filing cabinet:
%%
%% TDF etichette Migros GAB 7203.106
%%  Etichette indirizzi 21/foglio A4
%%
%%  Per la stampante EPSON WF4820
%%
\unitlength=1mm
%%
    \hoffset=-25.7mm
    \voffset=-28.95mm
\ticketNumbers{3}{7}
\ticketSize{70}{42.4}       %% in \unitlength
\ticketDistance{0}{0}       %% in \unitlength

%% Ricordarsi le dimensioni effettive quanto si stampa il PDF.

The flashcard front (my backside), should have 2 arguments, in case I need tu put a second password.....
I don't get it where is this distinction from the front and the backside, with the \backside command

Sorry, but you know what you're trying to do, we don't. Please, add some code.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with \documentclass{...} and ending with \end{document}.
